# Create a column that categorizes a number rating as Positive, Neutral, Negative

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column that categorizes a number rating as Positive, Neutral, Negative based on a value in an adjacent column in a dataframe. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
#create Target Column "Positive, Neutral, Negative"
df['Target'] = df.StarsInt.map((5:'Positive',4:'Positive',3:'Neutral',2:'Negative',1:'Negative'))
```

Comment: And exactly what difficulties/problems have you encountered? What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: I would use `pd.cut`.  Like this:  `pd.cut(df['StarsInt'], bins=[0,2,3,6], labels=['Negative', 'Nuetral', 'Positive'])'

Comment: are there values ​​of type float?

Answer (score 2):

Use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html?highlight=select#numpy.select)

```
conditions = [
    df.StarsInt >= 4,
    df.StarsInt == 3,
    df.StarsInt <= 2,
]

values = ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative']

df['Target'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Comment: or `conditions = [
    df.StarsInt >= 4,
    df.StarsInt <= 2
]` .....`values = ['Positive', 'Negative']` .... `np.select(conditions, values, default='Neutral')`

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(s, bins=[0,2,3,6], labels=['Negative', 'Nuetral', 'Positive'])
```

Output:

```
1    Negative
2    Negative
3     Nuetral
4    Positive
5    Positive
6    Positive
```

Comment: Great answer! Considering the fact that output column is categorical.

Comment: @Vishnudev Thank you.